# How I write two reaction from click button

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

If I have button and I must execute at its click one javascript code and php code.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="....">
```

How can I write my onclick button? What function can I use? Anyone can help me?

Comment: If you want to execute two functions, you can : onclick="function1();function2();"

Answer (score 0):

1) If your question is: **how to run 2 function at the same time?**

**Answer:** `onClick="doSomething();doSomethingElse();"`

2) If your question is: **how to run php when button is clicked?** (probably, you mean run php without refresh of the page..)

**Answer:** you can make a request to php via **AJAX**.